# Yii2: MongoDB undefined namespace

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I installed the MongoDB extension for Yii2 Framework.
Eventhough it has installed and my Yii application says I have MongoDB support I cannot use the namespace yii\mongodb anywhere in my code.

It tells me that mongodb is an undefined namespace.
I installed it as said on the git page and it installed without any errors, so I'm stuck.

I'm using the **Yii2 Basic template** and I have added:

```
'class' => 'yii\mongodb\Connection',
'dsn' => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/yii2basic'
```

To my **db.php**.

Answer (score 0):

In yii's documentation the namespace have an extra slash like this:

```
'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
'dsn' => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/yii2basic'
```

But add it as a component configuration in config,
watch this:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-mongodb-index.html